# jquery ajax sortable pass data in object as key value after serialize

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jquery ui sortable to reorder a list via php, I get the ids like so:

```
var ids = $('#sort1').sortable('serialize');
```

It works fine when on `update` in the ajax call I pass the `data` in the ajax call like so:

```
data: ids
```

And then catch in inside my php script like so (notice singular id):

```
$getids = $_POST['id'];
```

All that works fine, however I want to pass the data inside an object because there are other things I want to pass along as well, but it does not seem to be working.

I tried:

```
data: {
    id: ids
},
```

then I get this php error:

```
 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\sortable\sort.php on line 8
```

And I also tried changing `$getids = $_POST['id'];` to `$getids = $_POST['ids'];` but then I get unidentifed index and also invalid argument error.

How can I pass the `ids` inside an object as key value pair?

**EDIT:**

the foreach code

```
$count = 1;
foreach ($getids as $key => $id) {
    $q = "UPDATE titles SET sorting='$count', parent_id='1' WHERE id='$id'";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

    if ($r) {
        echo 'done <br>';
    } else {
        echo 'problem <br>' . mysqli_error($dbc);
    }
    $count++;
}
```

Comment: print ``$_POST`` and see what data you are getting and share the ``foreach`` code.

Comment: I just added the foreach code. as for the $_POST, do you mean to print in when everything works or when exactly?

Comment: i mean to say print $_POST to just see what data its giving.  I guess ``$getids`` is not an array.

Comment: yes, when i pass `data: ids` (which works) it prints a normal php array, when I pass it as `data: {id: ids}` I get: `id[]=2&id[]=3&id[]=5&id[]=1&id[]=6`

Comment: Screw it, I ended up stripping everything except for the numbers and the ampersands and exploding it into an array, though I suspect there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and came across this post, as it doesn't include any code to solve the issue. I finally found a solution that worked for me...

In my Ajax request I converted my sortable UI to an array using the following:

```
var data = $(this).sortable('toArray');
```

Then the Ajax request was sent the following way:

```
data: { sectiononelink: data, currentUserID: user_id },
```

Then because the sortable to array function gave me a string such as sectionone-asectionone-bsectionone-csectionone-d etc... I only wanted the letters after the "sectionone-" part of the string as I was looking to order a list in my html using the letters a - z.

In my PHP I used a foreach loop which contained:

```
$profileLinkOrder = "";

foreach($_POST['sectiononelink'] as $value)
{
    $profileLinkOrder .= substr(strstr($value, "-"), 1);
}
```

Then the variable $profileLinkOrder would come out like abcdefg etc... Depending on how I had my sortable UI list on my HTML page.

This worked for me so I hope someone else can use this to solve this problem. I could not find any other solutions on the web. Let me know if this helps.